# Hide/Remove Word from div using Css or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying remove/hide a specific word(ILS) from the div...I have no access to the html files of theme so i can only view the html through inspect element of browser...Is there any way i can hide/remove this word(ILS) by using Css or Jquery....Please help me to resolve this problem.

**Here is the div structure showing in the browser:**

```
<div class="ordr-dtls-trans-line">
    <span>סיכום ביניים</span>
    <!-- react-text: 63 -->
    ILS ₪0.15
    <!-- /react-text -->
</div>
```

Comment: is this text wrapped in some container, or it is exactly like the example you shared?

Comment: _**I have no access to the html files of theme so i can only view the html through inspect element of browser**_-> then you can't because you need to add js or css to files for working

Comment: have you tried snatching the `span` and then replacing the `parent` html using jQuery `html()`

Comment: What's the text you want to hide and when?

Comment: i tried that but didn't worked

Comment: @liam....i want to hide or remove ILS

Comment: no need to repeat the same question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `ILS` from the div content. Just get the entire HTML from `div` with class `ordr-dtls-trans-line` and then replace the word `ILS`. This is done this way because the text `ILS ₪0.15` do not have a tag surrounded to it. Otherwise we could use that tag to remove that text.

```js
var divElem = $('.ordr-dtls-trans-line');
var newContent = divElem.html().replace('ILS','');
divElem.html(newContent)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ordr-dtls-trans-line">
    <span>סיכום ביניים</span>
    <!-- react-text: 63 -->
    ILS ₪0.15
    <!-- /react-text -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot....u saved my time

Comment: Glad to help you.